# Find frequencies of a specific property value in a list<object>

Tags: c#, linq, list, frequency

How can I find the frequencies of the `Age` property for the `List<Person>`?

```
var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person {Name = "Jonh", Age = 10},
    new Person {Name = "Jack", Age = 12},
    new Person {Name = "Sara", Age = 10},
    new Person {Name = "Dave", Age = 10},
    new Person {Name = "Jude", Age = 12}
};

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }
}
```

So I want my `Person` objects to be updated to have the `Frequency` value.

```
Name             Age              Frequency      
----------------------------------------------
Jonh             10               3              
Jack             12               2              
Sara             10               3              
Dave             10               3              
Jude             12               2
```

Comment: you want to update person object with frquancy?

Comment: @DhavalPatel Yes Dhaval, I want to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var countByAge = people.GroupBy(x => x.Age)
                       .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

foreach(var person in people)
{
    person.Frequency = countByAge[person.Age];
}
```

Comment: is'nt there any way without iterating?

Comment: No, you have to iterate `people` at least once, otherwise how would you set `Frequency` on each instance?

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
foreach(var item in people)
{
  item.Frequency = people.Count(x=>x.Age == item.Age);
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but less efficient, *O(n^2)* solution.

Comment: yes i was trying to make some way without loop but failed

Comment: You need [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)...  something like `dictionary.ContainsKey(item.Age) ? dicitionary[item.Age] : ComputeAgeCountAndCache(dictionary, people, item.Age)`?